# Convert .json array like file to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

Trying to import .json file with format
`{"MIM01": {"air_temperature_2m": [271.64999999999998, 271.63999999999999]}, "time": [1646092800, 1646092860]}`
(where "MIM01" is simply the weather station id) as pandas dataframe

with code:

```
df = d.read_json(r'[..].json', lines=True, orient="dict", typ='frame', convert_axes=True)
df2 = pd.json_normalize(df)
```

results in following df:

```
                                  air_temperature_2m                                               time
0  [271.64999999999998, 271.63999999999999]  [1646092800, 1646092860]
```

Any ideas how I can restructure the df into columns? Thanks a lot!

edit: sample of the desired result:

|  | air_temperature_2m | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 271.64999999999998 | 1646092800 |
| 1 | 271.63999999999999 | 1646092860 |

Comment: You should show a sample of the desired result. Maybe the `explode` method is what you are looking for.

Comment: You only have one station id in your data file?

Comment: Yes, and it's basically irrelevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple station_id in each file, you can use:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

with open('data.json') as fp:
    data = json.load(fp)

ts = data.pop('time')
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(d).assign(time=ts, station_id=st)
                   for st, d in data.items()], ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   air_temperature_2m        time station_id
0              271.65  1646092800      MIM01
1              271.64  1646092860      MIM01
2              271.65  1646092800      MIM02
3              271.64  1646092860      MIM02
```

`data.json`:

```
{
    "MIM01": {
        "air_temperature_2m": [
            271.65,
            271.64
        ]
    },
    "MIM02": {
        "air_temperature_2m": [
            271.65,
            271.64
        ]
    },
    "time": [
        1646092800,
        1646092860
    ]
}
```

Comment: @simulacron. I tried to extrapolate the data from your file. Does my input file look like yours?

Comment: Thanks, that worked well and was more than I could have asked for!
Also, Michael Butschers reference to .explode was very helpful, thanks